# Get the inner HTML of an <a> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, responsive-design

I am building a dynamic menu for a responsive page in which the left side menu hides and turns into a different menu using the [slicknav](https://github.com/ComputerWolf/SlickNav) solution.

Now, what I want to do is for the left menu's first link to become the title of the menu.

I can't give the  tag that I need an ID because the menu is hard coded, so I need a different solution to find the inner HTML of it.

This is the HTML that I have:

```
<ul id="child_nav">
<li class="nav-title"><a href="#">My List title</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

And this is what I've been able to do with some programing to get the label of the menu to be the "My List Title" from the HTML above:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var E = document.getElementsByClassName('nav-title').innerHTML;

        $('#child_nav').slicknav({
            label: E
        });
});
</script>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're already using jQuery, use its selector to find the single element instead `getElementsByClassName`, which can return multiple elements.

```
$("#child_nav li.nav-title:first a").text();
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KrFs9/

Answer (score 4):

`getElementsByClassName` is **plural**, it returns **all** the elements with the given class name, so it returns a NodeList not a single HTML Element.

You need to treat it like an array and either pull the first item off it or loop over it with `for`.

Alternatively, since you are using jQuery, just use jQuery. The `html()` method will give you the inner HTML of the first element in the jQuery object.

```
jQuery('.nav-title').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish it:

```
var myLabel = $('.nav-title:first').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

try like

```
$(".child_nav li a:first").html()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        var title = $('#child_nav .nav-title a:first').html();

        $('#child_nav').slicknav({
            label: title
        });
    });
</script>
```